# Aggregate a set of unique values from all documents in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, aggregate

I'm trying to create a view in CouchDB that returns groups of unique values. E.g., a list of all unique brands and categories.

**map function**

```
function (doc) {
  emit("brands", [doc.brand]);
  emit("categories", [doc.category]);
}
```

**reduce function**

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
  return values.reduce(function(acc, value) {
    if (acc.indexOf(value[0]) === -1) {
      return acc.concat(value);
    }

    return acc;
  });
}
```

then I call that view with `group=true`, `group_level=2`. The grouping is correct, but the values aren't unique. The `value` is an array containing duplicates.

What I'm trying to achieve is basically having the `key` be the group name, e.g., `brands`, and the value be the aggregated unique values, e.g., `["Brand A", "Brand B"]`.

**Given the following documents**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "brand": "Brand A",
    "category": "Category A",
    "colors": [
      "Red",
      "White"
    ]
  },
    {
    "_id": "2",
    "brand": "Brand B",
    "category": "Category B",
    "colors": [
      "Blue",
      "White"
    ]
  },
    {
    "_id": "3",
    "brand": "Brand A",
    "category": "Category B",
    "colors": [
      "Green",
      "Red"
    ]
  }
]
```

**When I query then view in CouchDB, I'd like to get the following result back**

```
{
  "brands": ["Brand A", "Brand B"],
  "categories": ["Category A", "Category B"],
  "colors": ["Red", "White", "Blue", "Green"]
}
```

**Note:** The result above is just a demonstration of what I expect the view to return. It does not have to be structured as such (not even sure it's possible).

Comment: Please show your current code. What about it isn't working?

Comment: @Flimzy I've added an example for retrieving unique values for one property now.

Comment: And where is the associated reduce function?

Comment: I've now updated the question with both my map and reduce function. I've stated what's working and what's not. I've also included an example of what I try to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer this myself.

First, we want to define a map function that emit the group name as the key and the value wrapped in an array (making `rereduce` easier).

**map function**

```js
function (doc) {
  emit("brands", [doc.brand]);
  emit("categories", [doc.category]);
  doc.colors.forEach(function(color) {
    emit("colors", [color]);
  })
}
```

The we define a custom **reduce** function

```js
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
  return values.reduce(function(acc, value) {
    value.forEach(function(v) {
      if (acc.indexOf(v) === -1) {
        return acc.push(v);
      }
    });

    return acc;
  });
}
```

Now, calling the view with `group=true` and `group_level=1` will yield the following result:

```
    
+------------+-----------------------------------+
|    key     |               value               |
+------------+-----------------------------------+
| brands     | ["Brand A", "Brand B"]            |
| categories | ["Category A", "Category B"]      |
| colors     | ["Red", "White", "Blue", "Green"] |
+------------+-----------------------------------+
```